# Parse error with php function

Tags: php

I've been going through w3schools trying to get to grips with php. I've done a little Java and C++ in the past but nothing web side. I can't figure out why I'm getting a parse error

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php

// calling a variable can be done with $variable or . $Variable .
// php is loosely typed - you do not have to tell it that a var is a int or string etc


$color = "red"; //variables are case sensitive

echo "My car is " . $color . "<br>";


//scopes for vars are either local, global or static. Local are declared inside a function and global are declared outside a function

function myTest()
{
    $x = 5; //local scope
    echo "<p> Variable X inside function is: $x</p>;
}


?>

</body>
</html>
```

This returns a "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\phpinfo.php on line 28"

This runs fine with the function removed. What am I missing?

Comment: `is: $x</p>;` your missing a quote.

Comment: Get a good IDE/Editor with syntax checking. It will go a long way to saving you headaches.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You missed the closing double quote (`"`) on your `echo` line.

Change this line:

```
echo "<p> Variable X inside function is: $x</p>;
```

To this:

```
echo "<p> Variable X inside function is: $x</p>";
```

Also use good syntax editor. as @aynber suggest.

Comment: I feel like an idiot. Thank you!